# will session.clear() the all the persistent objects before transaction.commit ()?

Tags: hibernate, orm

Here is my situation:

```
session.beginTransaction();
Note note=new Note();
note.setName("hello");
session.save(note);
session.flush();
session.clear();----will it clear the note object from the session?
transaction.commit();
```

Will the object be saved in the database?

Comment: I think it should.Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should. Not sure though.

better if You to run the code to see the results.

`session.save(note);` firing insert. 
  `session.flush();session.clear();` is  firing all queries in buffer if any. 
`commit` will `commit` the transaction to DB.